# How has this arrangement of RAID disks occurred and is it recoverable?

Tags: centos, data-recovery, software-raid

I some months ago set up two RAID arrays for a system under CentOS 7. I was somewhat confused that the device list included two entries for each array, i.e. one had /dev/md126 and /dev/md126p1. The other was similar, /dev/md127 and /dev/md127p1. I rationalised this as each having a 'physical' device and a partition device, but it bothered me a bit.

Come today, I had outgrown one of the arrays and was looking to expand it, somewhat ham-fistedly.

I started by adding the new drive in the GUI, though it added itself as a spare, not as an active drive. I then started back down the mdadm route, using the --add option, then the --grow options on the /dev/md126p1 device. md126 grew by 1TB as expected, however md126p1 resisted, staying at its original 2TB size. After significant searching and trying to piece it together I got hold of parted, which refused to play ball, suggesting the drive was perfectly sized for its container and no expansion was necessary.

Going somewhat more brutal I found gdisk and, I thought on the back of the wisdom of its author in several forum posts, rewrote the backup GPT info to the end of the drive win gdisk. The suggestion was the false end might be constraining the growth, and moving it might allow the expansion. Well, this completely hosed the partition. Disks in the GUI still perceives the 2TB partition, but doesn't know what it is or how to use it. Parted now shows no partitions inside /dev/md126p1, though I'm not sure if that should make sense, if that device *is* a partition or should *house* one.

Parted detects the 2TB partition as being inside /dev/md126, gets the correct partition name etc. It just doesn't know how to recognise itself.

In gdisk before starting, I did save a backup of the GPT to a backup file, however restoring that backup didn't affect the loss of the partition.

It seems like a combination of my inexperience and a system that allows all manner of wrong configurations to just about exist and function has led me up this alley that perhaps noone has ever been before. However, if you think you have some helpful information I'd be really grateful.

Comment: I have managed after several restarts to execute fsck on the /dev/md126p1, which had the effect of recovering the partition to a usable state, however it still retains its 2TB size. I'm not sure if I'm exactly where I started on this or if it is in a yet more compromised state. I am making another backup of the data from this partition and will continue hitting it with hammers after this is done. Ideally I could learn something in this process rather than just blowing it all away and writing data from scratch.