# Partition resize in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, raid, resize2fs

I have a RAID 6 array set up under CentOS 7 which originally had four 1TB drives assigned, resulting in a total capacity of 2TB. After much fussing about [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214281/how-has-this-arrangement-of-raid-disks-occurred-and-is-it-recoverable), I was able to add a fifth drive to the array successfully, growing it out to 3TB. The confusion now is how to get the partition to grow out to the full 3TB size. According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/684781/resize-raid-partition-with-gpt-partition-layout-without-lvm) the sequence should be:

1. unmount
2. check partition
3. grow array
4. resize partition
5. check partition
6. mount

Which makes sense.

Having now grown the array, I am attempting to use `resize2fs` to resize the array, but it is telling me I don't have anywhere near enough space to expand into, that I'm asking for 786432000 and there are only 488315387 available. `e2fsck` tells me the partition is currently using 448736046 of its 488315387 available blocks. Where is the 488315387 limit coming from if not from the raid array?

**Edit: Relevant output from `lsblk`**

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md126           9:126  0   2.7T  0 raid6 
  └─md126p1     259:1    0   1.8T  0 md    
sdb               8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md126           9:126  0   2.7T  0 raid6 
  └─md126p1     259:1    0   1.8T  0 md    
sdc               8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md126           9:126  0   2.7T  0 raid6 
  └─md126p1     259:1    0   1.8T  0 md    
sdd               8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md126           9:126  0   2.7T  0 raid6 
  └─md126p1     259:1    0   1.8T  0 md    
sde               8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md126           9:126  0   2.7T  0 raid6 
  └─md126p1     259:1    0   1.8T  0 md
```

Comment: Output of `lsblk` would be a starter.

Comment: @JodkaLemon Have added the relevant output, was my first introduction to the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that a filesystem can only be expanded into the space that's seen as available on the block device you've put it onto. With partitions, that means the partition's starting and ending sector. As it stands now the kernel knows the space is there but your partition's end sector is essentially telling the filesystem to not use the new space. The `resize2fs` is for resizing the filesystem and so should come later in your workflow.

It looks like it's all on `md126p1` which might make this easier. Basically your `lsblk` shows that the underlying device is `md126` which is 2.7TB but the partition is only 1.8TB. So you need to use either `fdisk` or `gparted` (whichever the case may be) on the `md126` device and edit the first partition so that it ends on the last sector of the device instead of whatever it is now. You'll probably want all relevant filesystems unmounted when you do this. To get the kernel to pick up the new partition table you'll probably need to do a `partprobe` or do a full reboot.

Once the partition has been updated the filesystem inside that partition can be told to expand into it with the `resize2fs`.

Comment: `fdisk` I think doesn't like it because it's a 'big' partition, `gparted` I don't have, it doesn't appear to be in CentOS 7's sources, and `parted` has had the functionality removed to resize partitions... Any ideas?

Comment: if it's a single partition on the whole array, you can list the current configuration using any partitioning tool (and save this information somewhere as a safety precaution), then just delete the partition, and create a new one starting exactly where the original was but covering the entire space to the end.  You don't need to unmount anything to do this, but you will need to either `partprobe` or reboot to recognise the change.

Comment: Also, CentOS should have `sfdisk` :)

Comment: @galaxy that sounds somewhat nerve-wracking and low-level. I know deleting a partition doesn't go an write zeroes everywhere but I'm still a little lost as to the levels this is all happening on. At the physical level there's a long magnetic track containing data, at the other end is the file system. Between the two is sectors, blocks, cylinders etc., then physical partitions and virtual partitions and partition tables and file allocation table. Is there a good discussion anywhere on practically what it means to 'delete' a partition, 'format' a disk etc. and what actually is changed for each?

Comment: Further, wherever the information about partition definition exists (presumably in some dedicated location on the drive) there must be a value encoded for the end sector. If it is as simple as writing a new partition start and end, couldn't I just modify the end location of the existing partition?

Comment: @JCollins it is pretty nerve wracking, which is usually why people with non-trivial setups try to not rely on standard partitions as much as possible. In your case it probably would've been better to either use LVM RAID or use the MD raid to create the volumes that you then create your LVM PV's from. Easiest since you're creating a single partition on this device was to just create a filesystem directly on the md device and mount that without doing any partitioning. It's important to remember that we're talking about a very small amount of information that's easily (if tediously) regenerated.

Comment: If it's a GPT partition (which is what I take from you saying that it's a "big" partition) you'll have to use a tool like `parted` since `fdisk` only does the older partitions. CentOS will have `parted` available, it's possible you just have to manually install it with `yum install -y parted` or something. I have it on a RHEL7 machine so CentOS will definitely have it.

Comment: For what it means to "partition" a GPT disk [you can check out archlinux's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table) which explains what GPT is in more detail which should make it clearer what you're actually doing when you repartition.

Comment: For the unmounting, the kernel isn't going to want to re-read the partition table on a device if one of the partitions is still in use, so you do need to unmount. It used to work even if something was mounted but at some point around RHEL6 the kernel has started requiring all partitions be unused before it'll reload the partition table from a disk.

Comment: You should be able to just delete the partition and create a new one that takes up 100% of the disk. You should be able to let `parted` figure out what the ending sector number should be for you without having to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @Bratchley Perhaps this is something that has confused me for a while, that a filesystem can exist on a device without needing a containing 'partition'. This implies partitions can both exist next to filesystems and contain filesystems, all on the same drive. Is this to say a partition is effectively just finite size 'bookends' written around a block of data or is it more logical than that, that the partition information is written someplace  else?

Comment: No you can only do partitions or go without. To partition something means to split it up. If you split something in two you end up with two separate parts of the thing you split up. So you can't have a filesystem _beside_ a partition, you can only have a partition and decide to put something into it. Outside of the boot disk, partitions aren't strictly required in Unix/Linux and I usually avoid it unless I need the volume split into more than just one part.

Comment: So If I were to delete the partition and the data remained, wouldn't this amount to having the filesystem moved from the partition down to the device? Cheers for the help BTW, am learning on my feet.

Comment: No. it won't.  There is a partition table at the beginning of the device.  If you clear up the table it would be still there but empty.  A system would recognise the presence of the table, will try to read it and will find that there are no definitions, hence it will think that your device is empty.  This is why deleting/recreating the partition with the same starting sector info works - it's just a pointer in the table to where real data starts and what is the size of the chunk.

Comment: In contrast to the partitioned space, when you do not use partitions your filesystem / LVM /whatever data starts almost from the beginning of the device (there are still some reserved sectors at the beginning of the drive, but you may assume that your usage of space starts at the location where the partition information would have been.

Comment: So the follow-on naive question would be that if the partition was removed and the filesystem block of data was shifted to the front of the device, would *this* equate to moving it outside of the partition and onto the device directly. While I know I could jump on these instructions, they may work and solve this problem immediately, I would like to get to the point of actually understanding what is going on so I can solve the next problem without help - kind of like a surgeon wants to understand the whole body, not just the upcoming procedure, in case something goes wrong..!

Comment: Is the "upcoming procedure" to get it to where the filesystem is sitting directly on the RAID array instead of inside a partition? If so you might try unmounting the filesystem, using `resize2fs` to shrink it to the furthest it will go, using `dd if=/dev/md126p1 of=/someDir/partition bs=<howeverBIG> count=1` then once you have the filesystem image, you can use `dd` again to write it to the RAID array disk directly by doing something like `dd if=/someDir/partition of=/dev/md126p1` and then doing another `resize2fs` to grow the filesystem out again once it's on the actual MD device.

Comment: That procedure, of course, assumes you have some place that can temporarily store the filesystem image. You can try getting `dd` to pipe it to `gzip` or `bzip2` but I've never seen much storage gain and it just generates CPU heat more than it save in space.

Comment: @Bratchley from what I've read from you and galaxy, moving the filesystem down to the device doesn't seem completely necessary, but having more background information on what is actually going on and even your quite simple suggestion of copying the device entirely to a backup file is really great to know. What tends to happen in these operations is something basic goes wrong and I'm in limbo hunting for more answers. Question: is copying the whole partition to a file the equivalent to making an ISO image? Does the copy include information such as whether the filesystem is bootable?

Comment: Yeah, and in fact, if you wanted to verify that the filesystem image is usable you can do `losetup -f /someDir/partition` which will map the device to a device file and you can mount it somewhere else and make sure it all looks correct.